# How do I call functions inside render() method and still keep it pure?

Tags: react-native, dialog, state

I want to use a modal in my React Native app that ask the user to confirm his action.
The state looks like this:

```
state = {
    dialogVisible: false,
    confirmed: null
}
```

If the user confirms his delete action (turning confirmed to true), I want to execute my *delete()* method.
**Delete method:**

```
delete = () => {
    const { deckName } = this.props.navigation.state.params

    console.log('WAS CONFIRMED')
    this.setState({
        dialogVisible: false
    })

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Decks')
    removeDeckFromStorage(deckName)
    this.props.dispatch(removeDeck(deckName))


    this.setState({
        confirmed: null
    })
}

noDelete = () => {
    this.setState({
        dialogVisible: false
    })
    this.setState({
        confirmed: null
    })
}
```

When the user confirmed his action, the modal closes, and the delete is done. Afterwards, I want to set *confirmed* back to null re-use it later.
On the other hand, if the user does not confirm the modal by clicking **No**, the *noDelete()* method should be called, which just closes the modal and sets confirmed back to null.

My problem is now that I get a warning saying:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

That is because I check for the state of confirmed inside the *render()* method:

```
const { confirmed } = this.state

    if (confirmed){
        this.delete()
    }
    else if (confirmed === false){
        this.noDelete()
    }
```

I did this because when I checked the state of *confirmed* inside the *delete* method right after setting the *confirmed* state to true, it always said **null**.
I put the check inside render because after the *confirmed* state is changed through the user input, the component is re-rendered and thus giving me the right state for the query.

The dialog buttons each change the current *confirmed* state when clicked:

```
positiveButton={{
  title: "YES",
  onPress: () => this.setState({confirmed: true})
}}
```

So, how can I check for *confirmed* after it was set but still outside of the render method to keep it pure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never update the state in the render method. You should move your logic to the `delete` and `noDelete` functions instead.

I'm not sure how your modal is, however let's suppose it's something like this:

```
<View>    
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.delete}>
    <Text>Delete</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.noDelete}>
    <Text>No Delete</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

And in the `delete` and `noDelete` you simply remove the `setState({ confirmed })` since you're already calling the deletion from there.

Comment: Lol, you were so right. Just deleted this confirmed non-sense and hooked up the dialog confirm buttons to the delete and noDelete methods. Thank you very much.